# Postgresql Query Analyzer On Function

Tags: postgresql, function, analyzer

I've been using postgresql's explain syntax to analyze queries. However, I tried to run it against a custom function, sproc, but it does not analyze it. Is there a way to use explain against a function? If not natively is there a way to programmatically export the function body and have the query analyzer fun against that?

Comment: You can do this with the `auto_explain` module: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84414/explain-analyze-cannot-get-detailed-analyzed-results-for-queries-in-a-plpgsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, and given PostgreSQL's pluggable procedural languages it's unlikely to happen in a general way. In any case, EXPLAIN for functions that are more than just a query with parameters is perhaps not well-defined as a concept.

A typical work-around is to extract the query-part and do `PREPARE foo(...) ... SELECT` followed by `EXPLAIN EXECUTE foo(...)`. This lets you see the plan for a simple parameterised select.